# What is this called, and how can I do it? (Changing text)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, text

So as you can see on https://www.sketchapp.com/ they got something cool midway through the page, as you can see it changes the text automatically (Sketch is made for *Chaning text here* like you) after some time; and I was wondering how they did that and how it's called.

I'm trying to recreate something similar, Thanks

Comment: They use this jQuery plugin: http://codepen.io/jasondavis/full/fHdAt

Answer (score 0):

That you need is either a `setInterval` if you want the text to change on approximately the same time for an indefinite period or you `setTimeout` if you want to change the text only once. Below it is a snippet that uses the `setTimeout` as an example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('js-text');
    div.innerHTML = "Replaced <span class='redText'>Text</span>";
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.redText{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="js-text">Initial Text</div>
```